# Java Scanner: Continuous loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When I input any valid option (A,B,C) the if statement thinks that option is anything but A, B, or C, and will lead into a continuous loop.

```
package other;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu implements InterfaceMenu{

private String option;

public void greeting(){

    System.out.println("This program will use the Pythagorean Theorem");
    System.out.println("to calculate a missing side.\n");
    System.out.println("Choose an option!\n");
    System.out.println("Choose Option A for missing side c");
    System.out.println("Choose Option B for missing side b");
    System.out.println("Choose Option C for missing side a\n");

}

public String optionGet(){

    System.out.print("Choose an option: ");
    Scanner ad = new Scanner(System.in);
    option=ad.next().toUpperCase();

    if( (option=="A") || (option=="B") || (option=="C") ){
        ad.close();
    }
    else{
        optionGet();
    }

    return option;
}

}
```

Comment: Read [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) And if it's just one character then why not declare option as a char instead?

Comment: @PakkuDon To answer the second question, `Scanner#next()` returns a token and will do the work of skipping over whitespace for you; it would be more complicated to do that and return a `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from using the wrong method to compare strings, there is another serious problem:  `optionGet()` opens a new `Scanner` on `system.in`.  If the input contains an option that is not A, B, or C, then `optionGet()` calls itself *recursively*.  The recursive call does another

```
Scanner ad = new Scanner(System.in);
```

*while the first one is still open*.  There is no telling just what that will do, but it is likely to cause problems.  Do not do that.  Don't use recursion.  It's inappropriate here.  Instead, put the code that checks for options in a loop, and make sure `new Scanner` is outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the the `String.equals()` method. Not the `==` comparator. Whereas `.equals()` checks for equality between strings, `==` checks if their *references* are the same, which isn't what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

use `option.equalsIgnoreCase("A")` instead of ==. because == compares the reference variables and equals compars the content .

Answer (score 0):

In Java strings cannot be compared using the `==` identifier in the same way as you would for integers. Instead you can use `String.equals()`.

For what you have written however it may be best to compare characters however that will require changing the returned variable type within `optionGet()` to `public char optionGet()`. Doing this however will also require you to change the type of `option` to `char`. Changing the type to `char` will allow you to compare characters using `==`.

Also be sure to define `Scanner ad` outside of `optionGet()` as your current code is redefining it for every reiteration.

Your call as to what you think is easier.